# html parser android hidden input field

Tags: android, html, parsing, android-asynctask

I need some help 'cause i crash into error everytime i try to solve a problem. I am new to android programming. I want to extract a value from a certain field of an html site. This field is in a form and it hidden. The html is here.

```
<form autocomplete="off" id="Form1" action="login.aspx" method="post" name="Form1">
 <input type="hidden" value="" name="__EVENTTARGET">
 <input type="hidden" value="" name="__EVENTARGUMENT">
 <input type="hidden" value="dDwtMTg3MDkxXN199v0w==" name="__VIEWSTATE">
```

I tried to write some code but currently i have an error with asynctask. Before using asynctask the app just kept crashing and i figured out that the fault is possibly that the server takes some time to respond and this causes some problems. My code is the following.

The purpose is to send this value among with a username and password using the post method to the site and then check if it send and send some other values using post method.

Please help me! THANKS A TON FOR YOUR TIME!

```
 package com.example.parser;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Connection().execute();

        //TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //myText.setText("value =" + value);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        // try {
        // parsing();
        // } catch (IOException e) {
        // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public static void parsing(TextView textView1) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(
                "i have hidden my url :p ").get();
        Elements value = doc.select("[name=__VIEWSTATE]");
        textView1.setText("my value is" + value);
    }


    private class Connection extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            try {
                parsing(textView1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textView1.setText("my value is" + value)` is called from background thread. You must call it from UI thread.
Anyway, network related stuff must be done inside `doInBackgroud()` method and the UI related stuff such as `textview.setText()` should be call in `onPostExecute` method.

```
private class Connection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void , Elements> {

    @Override
    protected Elements doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Elements value = parsing(textView1);
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Elements value) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        textView1.setText("my value is" + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you VEEEEERY much. I wish i could vote up, but i don't have the reputation required.